# Javascript data-flow-with-ports visualization library

Tags: javascript, vis.js, gojs

I need a solution to visualize and edit data flow: action boxes with input and output ports, that user can connect.
Something like: [Data flow example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXmsW.png)

I've tried vis.js, but it doesn't have ports or boxes join dots, so I only able to connect nodes.
I've found go.js, and it suites, but it's not free and has a lot of additional functions I don't need.
Can you please advise javascript library to use?

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of question is off-topic at SO (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); but hey, there's a number of tools that allow to do this, why not just google? See https://modeling-languages.com/javascript-drawing-libraries-diagrams/ for example, there's a bunch of options

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider GoJS, https://gojs.net.
Look at these samples:
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/logicCircuit.html
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dataFlow.html
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html

For more discussion, please read: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/ports.html

If the licensing costs are too high, contact us to see if you qualify for discounts.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried d3 js examples? They have some example projects concerning data flow. github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: Yes, I saw this page. But there are no suitable visualization